# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem, when i m run my code then error is occured that ""*System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.*"".
And Datatype is Number.

plz suggest me regarding that.

"*Code*

```
 protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Geeta/Desktop/eTimeTrackLite1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "insert into Employees (EmployeeName,EmployeeCode,Designation,Grade,Team,Location,EmployementType,HolidayGroup) values ('" + txt_empname.Text + "','" + txt_code.Text + "', '"+ Convert.ToString(dp_designation.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_grade.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_team.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_location.SelectedItem)+"', '"+Convert.ToString(dp_emptype.SelectedItem)+"',  '"+Convert.ToString(dp_holigroup.SelectedItem)+"')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindGridData();
    }
```

"Thanks"

Answer (score 1):

You put strings as values in your insert startement and some of your db values are not of type string. That is causing the error.

Look at your table definition and convert the parameters of your insert statement to the correct types.